# how i can i handle the returned Json to construct another Ajax.actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have the following Ajax.actionlink which will the action method and return a JSON:-

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Start Process", "StartProcess", "Home",
new { name = "BuisnessProcess" },
new AjaxOptions 
    {   HttpMethod = "POST",
        LoadingElementId = "tobehide2",
        UpdateTargetId = "startprocess",
        OnSuccess = "Animate" }) 
</div> <img id="tobehide2" src="~/Content/ajax-loading2.gif" />
```

Currently when the user clicks on the link it will display the JSON info in the browser:-

```
{"activityId":"2119_666_BuisnessProcess_process1_setverialbe","processId":"666_BuisnessProcess_process1"}
```

But what i trying to do is to build another Ajax.actionlink based on the returned Json and pass the `activityId` as a new parameter to the Ajax.actionlink.

Best Regards

**:::UPDATED:::**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StartProcess(string name)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {

        try
        {
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
            query["j_username"] = "kermit";
            query["hash"] = "9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66";
            query["loginAs"] = User.Identity.Name;
            query["imagurl"] = "123";

            var url = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/start/" + name.ToString() + ":28:process1");

            url.Query = query.ToString();
            string json = client.DownloadString(url.ToString());

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            return Content("Process started succsfully. Returned values are :-" + json);
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {

            return Content("", "application/json");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you return data in action, to combine html string.

```
<a href="xxx">test</a>
```

to UpdataTargetId : startprocess.

---

when you return the json to view, then execute "Animate" function.
so, you can construct the link in Animate.

```
function Animate(result)
{
    $(result).each(function(index, item){
        // todo construct the link
    });
}
```

Comment: but how i will pass the JSON back to the partial view to construct the link. I have updated my original question with the action method code. Best Regards

Comment: you can construct the link in Animate.

Comment: thanks to your reply,, but this returned me back to my original concern,, on how to build the ajax.actionlink based on the returned Json object..